# Is 'in a week or three' correct English?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

The other day I had an argument with a fellow translator of English about the correctness of the expression **'in a week or three'**, which, in her opinion, is incorrect and may even be described as 'Dunglish'.

My gut feeling tells me there's nothing wrong with it, and any advice from native speakers of English would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think it sounds slightly jokey or even a tiny bit sarcastic. Obviously the idiomatic version is "a week or two", so your version sounds to me like "a week or two or perhaps more, but I'm not really sure how many more".

Comment: It sounds distinctly odd. I would wonder if you were trying to make a joke.

Comment: Definitely **don't** use it in your translation work. It is not idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I am aware of it that the 'three' version may sound a little funny (punny may be the appropriate word here (;-) , but as a  playful anology of the standing expression with 'two' I see no harm in using it in the title of a song: "In a week or three, I will be in Tennessee"

Comment: (sorry, I meant to write to Mick, not Mike)

Comment: As a song title, it looks just fine. Don't worry about the *Mike*. My friends call me all sorts of things.

Comment: @TeeBee *All* the context should be presented *in the question.* The style of a song title is likely to be different from a research paper for the board of directors.

Comment: It's a common jocular modification of the even more common "in a week or two", which implies that the event being considered is more than a "few" days out, but (probably) not more than two weeks.

Comment: Summarising: Grammaticality: no problem. Idiomaticity: unusual and hence quirky. Thus register: should be confined to informal / humorous.

Comment: Here's a 'Thanks' to all contributors for their comments. I propose to consider this topic as sufficiently dealt with now and, therefore, closed.

Comment: With apologies to Oliver Twist, Charles Dickens, and Lionel Bart, [*You've got to pick a pocket **or three**!*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-t5PB2Y0_E)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, there is nothing wrong with the phrase.  It is uncommon and has a specific use.  It is a modification of the common phrase, "in a week or two".  Its intention is to mean the same as its root phrase except the anticipation will make it seem longer.

It is also used in a derogatory sense when an entity frequently over promises on delivery schedules.

Answer (score -2):

She's right, you lost this one. One might say "in one to three weeks." But that sounds more definite than "ln a week or two". Keep trying, perhaps in a "week or three" you'll best her yet.

Comment: This is perfectly grammatical.  You are right that the normal collocation is “a week or two” but “a week of three” parses exactly the same as “a week or two” and “a week or three” might be used by a native English speaker in a jocular way.